# Undertanding django template operator 'pipe'

Tags: django, templates

***entry.courses.all|join:***

- I can't figure out why join and | are used and why we used all here.
  I am having a hard time in understanding this soo please help me
  figure out what this is.
  can someone suggest me the best way to learn django as fast as possible as most of the tutorials are basic. Thank you

Comment: This is too broad to be explained here and not a good fit for Stack Overflow format. I suggest you to start from those basic tutorials as you seem to be missing the most fundamental concepts about Django.

Comment: Official Document has pretty good example, which will help you. You can also get good youtube channels if you want to learn from video. **Everything takes time so don't hurry keep practicing**. May be Reddit or Quora is better option for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join

join is a bulit-in template filter, and works the same as regular python's join function.

In your case, the output would be a string formed by all your courses concatenated by ':' (if this char is part of your code..)