# Removing brackets and quotes from list in django template?

Tags: python, django

**Context**
I'm using Django to extract data from an API - which is then presented in a template. The data extracted is a list of genres. The list contains quotes and brackets when used via context.

**Question**
How to remove brackets and quotes from list in snippet below?

- Refer to objects, "genres" and "prodc", in views.py file
- Refer to context.genres and context.prodc in HTML

**Snippet**
[image]

**Views.py**

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    # template_name = 'home.html'
    def get(self,request):
        if 'movie' in request.GET:
            api_key = xxxx
            id = request.GET['movie']
            url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={}&language=en-US&query={}&include_adult=false'
            # payload = {'q': , 'appid': 'xxxxxx'}
            response = requests.get(url.format(api_key,id))

            # successful request
            if response.status_code == 200:

                # Parse json output for key value pairs 
                tmdb = response.json()

                # backdrop image -- tmdb for each movie
                backdrop_path = tmdb['results'][0]['backdrop_path']
                url_backdrop = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original'+backdrop_path 

                # poster image -- tmdb for each movie
                poster_path = tmdb['results'][0]['poster_path']
                url_poster = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original'+poster_path     

                                # 2nd get request for info on individual movie
                id_1 = tmdb['results'][0]['id']
                api_key_1 = xxxx
                url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key={}&language=en-US'
                tmdb_1 = requests.get(url.format(id_1,api_key_1)).json()

                # genres list
                genres = []
                for i in range(len(tmdb_1['genres'])):
                    genres.append(tmdb_1['genres'][i]['name'])
                eeeee = str(genres)[1:-1]
                
                # prod comps list
                prodc = []
                for i in range(len(tmdb_1['production_companies'])):
                    prodc.append(tmdb_1['production_companies'][i]['name'])

                context = {
                    'title': tmdb['results'][0]['original_title'],
                    'overview': tmdb['results'][0]['overview'],
                    'release_date': tmdb['results'][0]['release_date'],
                    'vote_average': tmdb['results'][0]['vote_average'],
                    'vote_count': tmdb['results'][0]['vote_count'],
                    'backdrop_path' : tmdb['results'][0]['backdrop_path'],
                    'backdrop' : url_backdrop,
                    'poster' : url_poster,
                    'runtime' : tmdb_1['runtime'],
                    'boxoffice' : tmdb_1['revenue'],
                    'tagline' : tmdb_1['tagline'],
                    'genres' : genres,
                    'prodc' : prodc
                    }
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'context': context}) 
            

            else: # returns homepage if invalid name is given in form
                    return render(request, 'home.html')

        else: # Homepage without GET request
            return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**HTML**

```
    {% if context.title %}
    <div class="w-7/12 col-span-1 pcard">   
        <div  class="wh pb-4 lato">{{context.title}}</div>
        <div class="gr tagline">{{context.tagline}}</div>
        <div class="wh py-3">{{context.overview}}</div>
        <div class="gr pt-3">{{context.genres}}</div>
        <div class="wh pb-3">{{context.prodc}}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I didn't work much with either `Django` or `class` so far, but I shoud be able to run your code. Is everything there that we need to run the code?

Comment: Try to put it inside a loop on your template. Like `{% for genre in context.genres %} {{ genre }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: maybe convert it to string before sending to template - `", ".join(genres)`. It is the most popular method to format list with strings.

Comment: @furas Or use join filter in template `{{ genres|join:" " }}`

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
The methods suggested by bdbd and @nigel222 both resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
The solutions suggested by @nigel222 in the comment above works best.
Refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255839/undertanding-django-template-operator-pipe) on how the Django template operator pipe works.

**HTML**

```
 {% if context.title %}
    <div class="w-7/12 col-span-1 pcard">   
        <div  class="wh pb-4 lato">{{context.title}}</div>
        <div class="gr tagline">{{context.tagline}}</div>
        <div class="wh py-3">{{context.overview}}</div>
        <div class="gr pt-3">{{ context.genres|join:", " }}</div>
        <div class="wh pb-3">{{context.prodc|join:", "}}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

**Snippet**
[image]